# ¿Como extraer datos de multiples Celdas en un Jtable

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

estoy intentando extraer varios datos de varias celdas selecionadas de un Jtable. La seleccion es libre.
Solo he logrado extraer un dato cada vez que clickeo una celda. He usado los siguientes comandos por parte de Jtable: *MiTabla.getSelectedRow* y *MiTabla.getSelectedColumn*.

Investigue y me salio que para varios datos use: *MiTabla.getSelectedRows* y *MiTabla.getSelectedColumns*.

Al momento de querer implementar los comando que he investigado me sale que no se puede convertir *Int[]* a *Int*. Y por lo tanto no consigo extraer datos en masa.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public class Haxcell{

public JFrame ventana;
private JTable tabla;
private DefaultTableModel dtm;
private final JToolBar barra = new JToolBar();   
private final JTextField coord = new JTextField("Ingrese Coordenadas. Ej: (A1,A2)");
private final JLabel mostrar = new JLabel("Mostrar en:");
private final JTextField impresion = new JTextField("Ingrese Celda de Resultado. Ej: (A3)");
private final JButton envia = new JButton("envia");

private final String [][] datos={{"hola","","","","","","","","",""},{"","nepe","","","","","","","",""},{"","","","","","","","","",""}
                                ,{"","","","","","","","","",""},{"","","","","","","","","",""},{"","","","","","","","","",""}
                                ,{"","","","","","","","","",""},{"","","","","","","","","",""},{"","","","","","","","","",""}
                                ,{"","","","","","","","","",""}};
private final String [] cabezera={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
private final String [] opera = {"SUMA","RESTA","PRODUCTO","DIVISION","MAXIMO","MINIMO","PROMEDIO"};
private final    JComboBox listaoper = new JComboBox(opera);

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Haxcell(){//CONSTRUCTOR
    ventana = new JFrame("Haxcell");
    ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout(30,30));//TIPO DE LAYOUT (SEPARACIONES)

    ventana.setSize(700,300);//TAMAÑO DE LA VENTANA

    seet_Tabla();
    seet_Toolbar();
    geet_Informacion(); 

    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Centrar ventana
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/logo.png")).getImage());//ICONO          
}
//FUNCION: CABEZERAS LATERALES, TABLA, SCROLL VERTICAL 
public final void seet_Tabla(){
    tabla = new JTable(datos,cabezera);

    JScrollPane Subirbajar = new JScrollPane(tabla);
    //Madre que permite seleccionar celdas
    tabla.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    tabla.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    tabla.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    //Tamaño de Tabla
    Subirbajar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,150));
    //Cabezeras laterales
    JTable filas = new RowNumberTable(tabla);
    Subirbajar.setRowHeaderView(filas);
    //POSICION DEL SCROLL
    Subirbajar.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER,filas.getTableHeader());

    ventana.add(Subirbajar);
}  
//FUNCION BARRA DE HERRAMIENTAS
public final void seet_Toolbar(){
    //VACIAR TEXTO AL HACER CLICK
    coord.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            coord.setText("");
        }
    });
    impresion.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            impresion.setText("");
        }
    });
    //BARRA ESTATICA
    barra.setFloatable(false);
    //PERSONALIZACION DE BARRA 
    barra.addSeparator();        barra.add(listaoper);
    barra.addSeparator();        barra.add(coord);
    barra.addSeparator();        barra.add(mostrar);
    barra.addSeparator();        barra.add(impresion);
    barra.addSeparator();        barra.add(envia);
    //AGREGAR BARRA CON UN BORDE AL INICIO
    ventana.add(barra,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
} 
public final void geet_Informacion(){//Obtener informacion
    envia.addActionListener(new ox());
}  
public static void main(String[] args) {
Haxcell table = new Haxcell();
};
private class ox implements ActionListener{//Clase para manipular la informacion
    //int[] rowindices = tabla.getSelectedRows();
    //int[] colindices = tabla.getSelectedColumns();
    Object cosa;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cosa = tabla.getValueAt(tabla.getSelectedRow(),tabla.getSelectedColumn());
        //(rowindices,colindices);
        tabla.setValueAt(cosa, 8, 2);
    }
};}
```

¿Como consigo extraer datos en masa(estoy usando una selecion libre), y ademas como guardaria esos datos, para su manipulacion posterior?

Gracias de antemano. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Paso 1: Crear una variable para manipular la data de la tabla

```
 DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object [][]{},new String [] {
    "MODIFICAR", "SEMESTRE", "CODIGO", "ASIGNATURA", "UC", "Prelacion_1", "Prelacion_2", "Prelacion_3","Prelacion_4","Prelacion_5","Prelacion_6"
     }){
      Class[] types = new Class [] {
    java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };

         public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
         }


     };
```

Paso 2: Asignar esa estructura a la tabla.

```
tabla.setModel(dtm);
```

paso 3: agregar los datos de interes separados por coma

```
dtm.addRow(informacion);
dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
```

opcional:
la informacion debe ser con la estructura de las columnas de la tabla, por lo que se debe rellenar con todos los valores asi sean null

```
Object [] informacion ={new Boolean(false),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null};
```

Comment: Logre resolver mi problema hace 15 dias, de todas formas gracias por su apoyo y atencion ingeniero.